# 'Shrink' image size of UIButton when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have this button (instance variable UIButton* _play) and I want it to decrease in size when tapped.  So if I tap and hold my finger on the button, I can see the change before it signals the new presented view controller to be loaded.  How do I get that to happen?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        _play = [UIButton playButtonCreate];
        [_play addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(playButton:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:_play];
        _play.frame = CGRectMake(107.5, 230, 105, 105);
    }

    - (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {
          PlayViewController* obj = [PlayViewController new];
          obj.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
          [self presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:nil];
          [self performSelector:@selector(setUpRockTitles) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    }
```

Comment: Do the shrinkage animation, and put a delay on the presentation of the view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to subclass `UIButton` to create your custom button. Here is just an example to achieve the 'shrink' effect you want.
In the `CustomButton.m` file:

```
@implementation CustomButton

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8); // set your own scale
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Then you can create the `CustomButton` just like a normal `UIButton`:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    _play = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(107.5, 230, 105, 105)];
    [_play addTarget:self
              action:@selector(playButton:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:_play];
}
```

Hope this helps!